# How to get a mean of the columns value in correlation with the mean of unique rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, unique

I have a dataframe that is like

```
A = matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
nrow = 10,  
ncol = 6,        
byrow = TRUE         
)
rownames(A) = c("2.4", "4.5", "8.5")
colnames(A) = c("X1", "X2", "X3")
```

Col have X values. I want to get all the values of the columns and average them by the average of unique of the rows. I tried converting the rows as.factor so that I have levels now. I do not know how to proceed to get what I would like to achieve. like the example below

```
...1 |X1|X2|X3
 2.4  5   4  2
 4.5  2   3  3
 8.5  4   2  4
```

Comment: The dimensions of your objects are not consistent.  Moreover, if the matrix is not square, how you want to intermix n1 rows with n2 columns where n1 != n2 is not clear.

Comment: In your example code the name vectors for the rows and columns do not match the dimensions of the matrix, which generates an error. Could you please edit it making sure it generates the intended dataframe?